# Azure function http call always returns Cross-Origin Request Blocked while on localhost

Tags: cors, azure-functions

I am just starting out with Azure functions and when I call the HTTP trigger function from Angular I get:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [MY_ENDPOINT]. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

I am running on localhost and an initial search pointed me to adding config to **local.settings.json**:

```
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "*",
    "CORSCredentials": false
  }
```

I also tried the above just `CORS` I have set my **local.settings.json** properties as found [here](https://www.koskila.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/2018-09-17_08-23-581.jpg).

I've also tried navigating to Project properties > Debug > Application arguments and adding

```
host start --useHttps --cors *
```

I have checked that I can get a response by running it through postman and the swagger ui associated with it. So I'm confident that this is not a red herring and that the problem is down the browsers CORS preflight request. But how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you run the Angular project locally and run the Azure Function on portal?

Comment: I am running it locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked out the answer.

My first attempt:
**local.settings.json**

```
"Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "*",
    "CORSCredentials": false
  }
```

failed because either `local.settings.json` was being ignored when I ran the project by pressing F5 or because I was serving my client over https and I was serving my function over http or possibly both.

My second attempt:
**Project -> Properties -> Debug -> Application arguments**

`host start --useHttps --cors *`
Press F5 to start

seemed to fail because I continued to get the error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:7071/api/foo. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

I was running my application in Firefox, but switching to chrome returned:

> net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Solution 1: (the hacky way to check the idea works)

1. copy azure endpoint and paste it in to the browser
2. accept the this site is unsafe message
3. reload the client

Solution 2:

1. create certificate
2. update `Project -> Properties -> Debug -> Application arguments` with:
   `host start --useHttps --cert \"myCert.pfx\" --password \"somePassword\"`
3. press F5
4. reload client

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the error locally, and solve it by doing the same thing with `local.settings.json`.

I asked if you run the Function on portal because you mentioned the **copy always** option. If you already deploy the Function to Azure, please set the **CORS** on **portal**.

[image]

Please let me know if you still haven't solved this problem.